# Loading from pickle slow/fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I'm using Gauss-Legendre integration to calculate an integral. To get the necessary roots of the Legendre polynomials, I have followed steps outlined [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Numerical_integration/Gauss-Legendre_Quadrature) and it works. To save me the time of generating the roots for high order polynomials, I have added a `try:`, `except:` routine to store and load roots generated on prior runs. However, above some number of roots this becomes very slow. For 20 roots, the loading delay is almost non-existent, for 25 it is noticable (on the order of several seconds) and for 30 roots it does not progress at all. (CPU at 100%, but nothing put out to console, no error message.) Why is that and what can I do better? After all, it should just read a list of floats from a file.

```
import math
import pickle

def Legendre(position, order):
    # calculates the value of the Legendre polynomial of any order at a position
    # has to be a separate function because of recursion
    if order == 0:
        return 1.0
    elif order == 1:
        return position
    else:
        return ((2 * order - 1.0) * position * Legendre(position, order - 1) - (order - 1) * Legendre(position,
                                                                                                      order - 2)) / float(
            order)


def Legendrederivative(position, order):
    # calculates the value of the derivative of the Legendre polynomial of any order at a position
    if order == 0:
        return 0.0
    elif order == 1:
        return 1.0
    else:
        return order / (math.pow(position, 2) - 1) * (
        position * Legendre(position, order) - Legendre(position, order - 1))


def Legendreroots(order, tolerance=10):
    try:
        with open('rootsfile' + str(order) + 't' + str(tolerance) + '.txt', 'r+') as filecontents:
            roots = pickle.load(filecontents)
        return roots
    except:
        if order == 0 or order == 1:
            raise ValueError('No roots possible')
        roots = []
        for counter in range(1, order + 1):
            x = math.cos(math.pi * (counter - 0.25) / (float(order) + 0.5))
            iterationcounter = 0
            dx = 10 * 10 ^ (-tolerance)
            while (abs(dx) > tolerance) and iterationcounter < 1000:
                dx = - Legendre(x, order) / Legendrederivative(x, order)
                x += dx
                iterationcounter += 1
                if iterationcounter == 999:
                    print 'Iteration warning!', dx
            roots.append(x)
            print 'root' + str(counter) + 'found!'
        with open('rootsfile' + str(order) + 't' + str(tolerance) + '.txt', 'w+') as filecontents:
            pickle.dump(roots, filecontents)
        return roots

roots = Legendreroots(20)
```

The first two functions are the function definitions of polynomial and its first derivative respectively, third function generates the roots and handles file I/O.